# How to parse SOAP Response (data in text format in one node), I am using c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

I have this soap response, wherein data is coming in text form in one node, please suggest appropriate way to parse this:

CP N  FRM/TO A/L FLT  COS DATE    TIME  ST FBC              S
01-O SYD MEL QF    401 Y  22MAY16  600A OK YQFLEX
                          BAG:1PC                           N
03-O AVV SYD QF   5602 Y  29MAY16  600A OK YQFLEX
                          BAG:1PC                           O

```
              **ENDORSEMENT/FARE CALCULATION**
```

ER:VALID ON QF SERVICES ONLY

FARE CALCULATION:                       FARE CALC INDICATOR: 0 
SYD QF MEL M/IT QF SYD M/IT END

```
               **FARE BREAKDOWN/FOP/TOUR CODE**
```

*TKT FARE DATA*         *AUDITOR*
 BASE:AUD  1320.78    BASE:AUD  1320.78
  TAX: QR     6.20     TAX: QR     6.20
  TAX: QR     4.70     TAX: QR     4.70
  TAX: WG     6.00     TAX: WG     6.00
  TTL:GBP   733.90     TTL:GBP   733.90
EQUIV:GBP   717.00     BBR:     0.543186

Comment: It's a plain text, not xml. So parse it manually, using regex or string functions.

Comment: Yes it's plain text, should I use c# tuple here? What is the best way to parse this text?